Can the president provide amnesty and expedite/fast-track all immigration proceedings?
Could the president for example,

Give amnesty to all undocumented immigrants regarding any crimes that may have been committed to enter the country. I believe Reagan did something like this?
Waive filing fees for all immigrants.
Fast track all applications for permanent residency and citizenship?

Effectively making the 11 M or so undocumented immigrants citizens?

"I believe Reagan did something like this": as far as I remember, Reagan asked congress to pass a law, and they did, which he of course signed into law.  To the extent that it is a "Reagan amnesty" it's because it was his idea, but it was not his unilateral action.


Could the president for example,

Give amnesty to all undocumented immigrants regarding any crimes that may have been committed to enter the country. I believe Raegan
did something like this?


The President can pardon federal crimes, but removing the criminal offense doesn't prevent undocumented immigrants from being deported, because they're deportable even if they didn't commit any crimes -- they are deportable due to their lack of status. And the President cannot grant permanent legal status under current law. (Even the President's ability to grant temporary status under current law has been legally challenged.)
Only Congress can grant permanent status. When people use the term "immigration amnesty", they are referring to Congress passing a law providing a pathway to permanent legal status to people who are already present, which is what happened during the Reagan administration (with the Immigration Reform and Control Act of 1986). This is not something that Reagan did by himself.


Waive filing fees for all immigrants.


The executive branch sets the fees for applications by regulation, and they already provide for fee waivers for certain applications, when the applicant cannot afford it. They could amend regulations to change the circumstances in which they grant fee waivers, but they would have to make up the reduction in fees somehow (e.g. make someone else pay more fees), because USCIS is mostly funded by fees. It doesn't receive money from the federal budget for processing applications.
And paying filing fees hasn't really been a problem for people trying to immigrate. Rather, it's the lack of a pathway to legally immigrate at all. I think almost any undocumented immigrant would consider being granted a pathway to legally immigrate worth many times more than the highest fees that exist now.


Fast track all applications for permanent residency and citizenship?

Effectively making the 11 M or so undocumented immigrants citizens?

What "applications" do you think need to be "fast-tracked"? The speed of applications isn't really a problem (e.g. in general people can stay in the US if they have a pending application for Adjustment of Status), and isn't really relevant to undocumented immigrants.
Someone in the US can't "apply for citizenship" unless they have been a permanent resident for a period of time first, or they have served in the US military (which foreigners without permanent residency cannot currently join). And someone can't "apply for permanent residency" unless they are in one of several narrow categories of legal immigration to the US. In most cases, you need to be petitioned as the spouse, parent, child, or sibling of a US citizen, or as the spouse or unmarried child of a US permanent resident, or petitioned by a US company that is offering to hire you (usually in a skilled position) after you immigrate. Most undocumented immigrants simply do not have such a US relative or US employer to petition them in the first place. These categories are set by law and are not something the President can change.
Even for the small fraction of people who do fit into one of those narrow family-based or employment-based categories, there are often impediments that prevent them from getting permanent residency. For people in most family-based or employment-based categories, other than the Immediate Relative category (spouse, parent, or unmarried under-21 child of US citizen), there is an annual cap on the number of visa numbers (which is set by law and the President cannot change), so there is a multi-year or multi-decade wait for visa numbers, of different lengths for each category. Furthermore, they cannot do Adjustment of Status (the process of getting permanent residency from within the US) if they are out of status. For people in the Immediate Relative category, there is no wait for visa numbers, and they do not have to be in status, but they need to have entered legally to do Adjustment of Status.
People who are petitioned in one of the narrow categories, but who entered illegally, or (for non-Immediate-Relative categories) who are out of status, and thus cannot to Adjustment of Status, can only immigrate through Consular Processing at a US consulate abroad, but leaving the US will trigger a ban, and waiting out the ban abroad for years is not really feasible for most people. An immigrant waiver for this ban is available if their US citizen or permanent resident spouse of parent will suffer "extreme hardship" if they can't be in the US; most immigrant don't have such a spouse or parent, and even if they did, "extreme hardship" is a standard that the vast majority of people cannot meet.
There are also other paths to legal immigration like asylum. But asylum is only for people fleeing persecution, and doesn't apply to the vast majority of people. Also you generally need to apply within 1 year of entry, and most undocumented immigrants who are already present can no longer apply. There is also the Diversity Visa lottery, but 1) most immigrants were born in countries that do not qualify, 2) even if they were born in a country that qualifies, the annual number of visas (set by law) is so low that even if someone applies every year of their life, their chance of getting it are very small, so it is not a feasible path to immigrate, and 3) for undocumented immigrants, there is still the problem that they cannot do Adjustment of Status due to being out of status, and leaving the US will trigger a ban, and they can't simply wait it out because even if you are selected for DV for a given year, you can no longer immigrate after the year is over.
So basically there is not much that can be done to provide or even ease a path to permanent residency or citizenship without Congress passing a new law.


Fast track all applications for permanent residency and citizenship?

Biden planned to fast-track citizenship for illegal immigrants who had lived in the US for at least 10 years and married a US citizen. This plan was ruled illegal. So Fast-tracking all applications for residency or citizenship would likely be ruled illegal as well.

Not relevant. The judge struck it down because they were "illegal foreign nationals", but the president could have simply excused the crime and provided amnesty/pardon -- that's what question calls for.

"Biden planned to fast-track citizenship for illegal immigrants who had lived in the US for at least 10 years and married a US citizen." That's not really what the program was. It was only to grant "parole-in-place" (i.e. parole someone who is already in the US), and nothing else. If that is granted, then the path to permanent residency (and, if they wish, citizenship) is something that already exists in the law.

Wait you can illegally be in a 1st world country for 10 years and not even get a legal status? Like how do you get a home, a job, medical care or whatnot without leaving a paper trail? Are the U.S. just so routinely criminal to make those off the books or so disorganized to keep an overview? Like for a country that literally has no sense of privacy and spies upon the entire world I'm really surprised.

@EvanCarroll not all "illegal foreign nationals" have committed a crime, and being out of status isn't a crime, so the president can't pardon it.  Even if it were, a pardon would only free someone of punishment for the crime; it wouldn't give them valid status.  Since they would still be out of status, they would still be deportable.

@haxor789 you certainly leave a paper trail; that doesn't lead to a valid immigration status.

@phoog Incorrect. By definition of being "illegal" they are against the law, hence they have committed a crime.

@haxor789 The US is very good at knowing what it wants to know and intentionally ignoring what they would rather not know. The current administration in the US is democrat, and they want illegal immigrants in the country to be become citizens and not be caught beforehand so they can vote (because most illegals tend to vote dem). Same reason the Reps want them out...

Not at all.  Not everything that is illegal is a crime, and immigration law is full of such things.  Because it's not a crime, the subject of a civil immigration enforcement action is not entitled to an attorney at government expense, among other things.  Some other examples of illegal acts that are not necessarily crimes include a landlord raising rent in the middle of a lease without any provision in the lease for the increase, parking your car in a no-parking zone, and letting your grass grow too high.

@phoog A crime is defined as “illegal activities”

@Starship there may be some people who define "crime" that way, but it is not the definition used by lawyers, judges, or legislatures.

Frameshift : even if it was legally feasible, this would be an utterly unproductive and undemocratic idea.
Assuming he somehow could effect this, legal-wise and time-wise, one wonders why a Democratic POTUS would do this, after just losing an election where immigration concerns were indicated a major concern in polls, including by substantial minorities of Democratic voters.
This is attempting an end-run around the recently expressed sentiment of the American electorate about immigration concerns.  Whether that sentiment is justified or not is irrelevant, a stricter handling of immigration is still what people voted for, especially given Trump's emphasis of the subject.
Let's take a counter example.
It is November 2028 and the Democratic Party has just resoundingly won the election, not least by campaigning on climate concerns which have repeatedly showed up in polls, even for Republican voters.
In the waning days of his presidency, should Trump aim to circumvent legislative channels as much as possible and grant exploration/exploitation leases for oil drilling to friendly companies?  In the expectation that this will be hard to reverse?
What's even more disturbing in this question is

Effectively making the 11 M or so undocumented immigrants citizens?

Thus making them Democratic voters, perhaps?
This answer is certainly not being posted from a PoV of appreciation towards Trump or his expressed intents of mass deportations.
This would be a massive breach of voters' trust and would scuttle the Democratic Party's chances in 2028
Plus, what the other answer said - it would get shot down in court.

Doesn't answer the question at all.

@ItalianPhilosopher The OP asked "Can it be theoretically be done" and you answered with "it is a bad idea". Doesn't answer if it can be done
